# remote hardhat - metamask connection issue

Tags: metamask, hardhat

I am trying to set up a dev website accessible from remote.
Thus I have install my application in AWS where I run a hardhat.
However I can not connect metamask to that instance. I keep on having an error that it could not fetch RPC
[image]

can someone helps me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardhat default chain id is 31337, did you try to use that as chainId?